# ng-grid change sorting order onchange of drop down

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am using ng-grid , i have implemented search functionality on it but i want to change orderby option by changing drop down value.

I wish to provide drop down on change of its value data soting should happen.

by default Sort-functionality is there which works on click of table heading but i need to change sorting order on change of dropdown.

This code i got from somewhere but i dont know how to use it ?

```
 $scope.gridOptions = { 
  data: 'gridData',
    columnDefs: [
      {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'}, 
      {field:'ageWord', displayName: 'Age'}
    ],
    sortInfo: {
      fields: ['age'],
      directions: ['asc']
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define values for the `sortInfo` and `useExternalSorting` of your grid options, like this:

```
$scope.gridOptions.useExternalSorting = true;

$scope.gridOptions.sortInfo = {
  fields: [$scope.selectedDropDownOption],  // <-- or whatever variable used to store selected option from dropdown
  directions: ['asc']
};
```

Answer (score 0):

e.g.: if you want to sort by `name`, you could set

```
sortInfo: { fields: ['name'], directions: ['asc']}
```

this would order your grid by name and ascending 
you also want to set `useExternalSorting = true` in your `gridOptions`.

i suggest you have a look at the [docu](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid) and [examples](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) pages

Comment: it is for initial setup , i need to change sorting order later

Comment: sorting should change with drop down

Answer (score 0):

I used following code ,,,

**HTML :**

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="sortColumn"></input>   
  <button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="updateSortInfo()">Sort</button>
```

**aap.js  ::**

```
$scope.updateSortInfo = function() {
      $scope.gridOptions.sortBy($scope.sortColumn);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reached here while searching for solution of similar thing. After trying all options I have applied this.

```
//Disable Grid Ui Sorting through header
    $scope.gridOptions.enableSorting = false;
//Apply angular 'orderBy' filter to data for grid ui
    $scope.resultSetTable = $filter('orderBy')($scope.gridData, 'YOUR_SORT_COLUMN');
// Apply data to grid ui
    $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.resultSetTable;
```